# How to get a specific column's value in the last row with data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm pretty new at JS and attempting to create a script that fires an email each time a form is filled out. The email needs to have a very specific title and body, which is created in my sheet.

Specifically, I need my subject line to be column I in the last row with data and my email body to be column F. I was able to get the script to select the proper last row, but I'm struggling to figure out how to get the correct column's value.

I currently have one piece of code I've tried, but I get the error

> TypeError: Cannot find function getValue in object 346. (line 7, file
>   "Code")Dismiss

```
function sendEmail() {
  // Fetch the email address - This is a specific email address in the sheet I need stuff to go to 
  var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Reference").getRange("F2");
  var emailAddress = emailRange.getValues();

  // Send Alert Email.
  var message = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow().getValue() // KMS Survey Text
  var subject = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1").getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow().getValue(); // KMS Survey Title
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets correct the second part of your function:

```
// Send Alert Email.
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
var lastRow = sheet.getRange("A1").getDataRegion().getLastRow();
var message = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 7).getValue(); // (F column is 7-th) KMS Survey Text
var subject = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 9).getValue(); // (I column is 9-th) KMS Survey Title
MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

The error was because of incorrect use of [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getLastRow()) method. Actually it returns a number, not object. Having a number we can reference to the desired last row cells and get their values.

In addition I recommend to use `getValue()` method instead of `getValues()` when the range contains a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

This will do exactly what you're looking for. I've cleaned up some of your variables because getting active spreadsheet, then sheet, then range etc is not good practice. You can define this once then use the defined variable to grab different ranges as you please.

```
function sendEmail() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var refSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Reference');
  var formSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');

  var lastRow = formSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
  var subject = formSheet.getRange(lastRow, 6).getValue(); //KMS Survey Text
  var message = formSheet.getRange(lastRow, 9).getValue(); //KMS Survey Title
  var emailAddress = refSheet.getRange("F2").getValue();

  // Send Alert Email.
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
}
```

Instead of `getRange().getDataRegion().getLastRow()`, you can use `getDataRange()` on a sheet to get the whole range of the data you've currently got on the sheet, then use `getLastRow()` on that instead like:

```
var lastRow = formSheet.getDataRange().getLastRow();
```

Then use this to get the range of your data for the email, note: `getRange()` rows/columns are indexed from 1, so Column F = 6, Column I = 9:

```
var subject = formSheet.getRange(lastRow, 6).getValue(); //KMS Survey Text
var message = formSheet.getRange(lastRow, 9).getValue(); //KMS Survey Title
```